# How do I get a functions calling convention with BOOST?

Tags: c++, boost, calling-convention

Using BOOST, I am trying to get the calling convention of a function, and to do this I am taking a similar approach as the individual who posted the same question - however their solution has not solved my problem.

Heres a link to their problem: [function calling convention with boost::function_types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381798/function-calling-convention-with-boostfunction-types)

I have attempted to get the calling convention using a similar approach but am getting compiler errors complaining that "cdecl_cc" is not defined. Heres a small snippet of my code:

```
#define BOOST_FT_COMMON_X86_CCs 1
#include <boost/function_types/config/config.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/is_function.hpp>

    static bool isCdecl()
    {
        if(boost::function_types::is_function<T, cdecl_cc>::value == true)
            return true;

                return false;
    }
```

The other user claims that by adding an include to boost/function_types/config/config.hpp and by defining BOOST_FT_COMMON_X86_CCs, there problem was solved - however It has not solved mine.

I've tried placing the includes and the definition inside of a precompiled header as well.

Looking at config.hpp I see an include to cc_names.hpp which lists the definition like so

```
#define BOOST_FT_BUILTIN_CC_NAMES \
  (( IMPLICIT           , implicit_cc , BOOST_PP_EMPTY                ))\
  (( CDECL              , cdecl_cc    , BOOST_PP_IDENTITY(__cdecl   ) ))\
  (( STDCALL            , stdcall_cc  , BOOST_PP_IDENTITY(__stdcall ) ))\
  (( PASCAL             , pascal_cc   , BOOST_PP_IDENTITY(pascal    ) ))\
  (( FASTCALL           , fastcall_cc , BOOST_PP_IDENTITY(__fastcall) ))\
  (( CLRCALL            , clrcall_cc  , BOOST_PP_IDENTITY(__clrcall ) ))\
  (( THISCALL           , thiscall_cc , BOOST_PP_IDENTITY(__thiscall) ))\
  (( IMPLICIT_THISCALL  , thiscall_cc , BOOST_PP_EMPTY                ))
```

I am not sure how one should interpret a definition like this, if someone could explain it to me I might be able to figure out how to solve my problem.

Sorry for all the BOOST related questions from me, I am fairly new to it and I am diving head first into one of the more difficult libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: `BOOST_FT_BUILTIN_CC_NAMES` is a _sequence_ of _tuples_.  Sequences and tuples are [preprocessor data structures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/) used in code generation by the Boost.Preprocessor library.  Somewhere, this macro is used, perhaps in a `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` (which iterates over the elements of the sequence) or one of its friends.

Comment: I suspect you need to qualify cdecl_cc with the appropriate namespace (boost::function_types). You may also need to `#include <boost/function_types/property_tags.hpp>`

Comment: @AlanStokes I wasn't aware that I had to qualify with the boost::function_types namespace as I was under the impression it was just a simple definition - the examples on the site also seem to assume you're already inside of the namespace. Anyway, your solution worked. Thanks :) If you could post it below I would mark it as the answer, if not I don't mind doing it myself. The link to the other question on stackoverflow confused me, as their example explicitly accesses is_function via the function_types namespace where as it then access _cdecl as if it were already present in their namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to qualify `cdecl_cc` with the `boost::function_types namespace`, and also `#include <boost/function_types/property_tags.hpp>`.

Boost is great, but the documentation can at times be obscure. I think they tend to write it as if it was part of the standard, so the namespace is implicit. But unless otherwise specified you should assume everything is in some namespace, either `boost` or a more specific one.